# Calculating moving average in R

Tags: r, statistics, moving-average

I've been trying to calculate the moving average over a vector in R. Ideally, I would like to write a function that calculates the MA over any number of lags. The mathematical steps i have to code are:
1. creating a dataset with 1:k lags for each column. 
2. Summing over the row
3. dividing by 2k+1

I'm stuck at step 2 right now.I can evaluate the sum for say 2 lags, but creating a formula for multiple lags is very cumbersome.

Here is where i am right now.

I have leveraged a code for calculating lags

```
lagpad <- function(x, k) {
  if (k>0) {
    return (c(rep(NA, k), x)[1 : length(x)] );
  }
  else {
    return (c(x[(-k+1) : length(x)], rep(NA, -k)));
  }
}
```

Suppose I calculate the MA over the following vector:

```
i<-1:50
rowSums(cbind(lagpad(i,1)[1:length(i)], lagpad(i,2)[1:length(i)]))
```

This works fine for 2. But if i want to calculate the MA for 20 lags, I'll have to cbind 20 columns. Is there a faster way to do this/ write this function?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to write a function or would function `rollmean` in package `zoo` do it?

Comment: I wanted to write a function to do it

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple function using differences of cumulative sums...

```
x <- 1:10

mav <- function(x, k){
  y <- c(0, cumsum(x))    #cumulative sums of x
  z <- y[-c(1:k)]         #discard first k values
  length(y) <- length(z)  #discard last k values of y
  return((z - y) / k)
}

mav(x,2)
[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5

mav(x,1)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

mav(x,4)
[1] 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5
```

Comment: that's a nice short definition, and probably good enough in most cases.  note that numeric stability is bad for all "small" numbers following a "large" one.  e.g. where `x = 10^(10:-10)` the last few elements will be truncated to zero with roundoff errors before that.  @dexter these subtle sorts of issues are why you really want to use library code where possible!